# introduction of a "big picture" in android notification increased the delivery rate

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

we have a scheduled notification being delivered to all our active users everyday, since past several years.

last month, we introduced a support for a Big Picture within a same notification.  after analysing the tracking data for the newly released App version, we found this -

- the Sent count remain stable (like before).
- the Delivery count is increased by 15%

we reverted the changes and the Delivery numbers came back to normal. Sent numbers remained unchanged.

after a week, we again turned on the Big Picture and the Delivery numbers immediately shoot-up by ~15%.

we have confirmed that, there is no bug in the tracking code and there are no duplicates in delivery tracking.  not sure what is causing the delivery to go high by just adding one attribute in the payload.

is there anyone who had faced similar issue with Big Picture on Android?
any clue for the troubleshooting?

this is the payload getting pushed to FCM with Big Picture

```
{
    "data": {
        "message": "Checkout your deal of the day",
        "category": "AB",
        "type": "AB",
        "pid": "",
        "title": "Daily Notification",
        "display_name": "Tom",
        "tid": "MVNINDg0NjQzOTN8",
        "channel_id": "daily_notif",
        "channel_name": "Daily Notification",
        "channel_priority": "high",
        "is_external_url": "",
        "url": "",
        "style": "bigPicture",
        "landing_url": "",
        "version": "",
        "landing_page": "daily_notifications",
        "actions":  [{
            "label": "View All"
        }],
        "img": "",
        "extras": {
             "big_picture": "http://somedomain.com/DR Big picture notif(RED).jpg"
        },
        "track": 2,
        "evt_ref": "WZpY2F0aW9u",
        "redirect_page": ""
    }
}
```